# Query against two values without duplication

Tags: view, couchdb, nosql

I'm trying to implement an autocompleting user search capability where you can search for someone with their name OR their email address.

My map function currently looks like this:

```
function (doc) { 
  if (doc.name && doc.email) {
    emit(doc.name, doc.id);
    emit(doc.email, doc.id);
  }
}
```

but this means that if someone's searching for a user whose name begins in the same way as their email address, in the inital stages of the request I'm getting two results for the same user.

Is there a way that I can query the name of a user, and if that doesn't match, then and only then query the email?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
function (doc) { 
  if (doc.name) {
    emit(doc.name, doc.id);
  }

  else if (doc.email) {
      emit(doc.email, doc.id);
  }

  else {console.log("No Match")}

}
```

Comment: Your help is much appreciated, thank you, but all the documents will have both fields, I rather want to be able to search both fields without returning duplicate documents if both the name and email match